# How to use Kaminari in an ActiveRecord dependent Gem that does not necessarily use Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, kaminari

I have a ruby gem that houses ActiveRecord models that are shared across multiple apps. This gem also contains several other shared classes that work with the models. One of these classes uses Kaminari, but when I put it in the gem, all tests failed from Kaminari related errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: http://mensfeld.pl/2014/12/sinatra-and-kaminari-without-any-views-and-without-padrino-helpers/

```
require 'kaminari'
require 'kaminari/hooks'

::Kaminari::Hooks.init
```

Hopefully this will save someone else the time and trouble!